# Editing OpenWeatherMap Icon with React and Webpack

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, webpack, openweathermap

I am currently learning React with Webpack. I am looking to edit the icons that were given by the [OpenWeatherMap's data](https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions).

However, their icon starts with a number. An example is "10d". In Javascript, I am not allowed to create a variable starting with number.

How should I tackle this? I am using `file-loader` for my webpack

**My solution**

1. Find my own custom icons and named accordingly to the API's icon name.
2. `import 01d from "./WeatherIcons/10d.svg"` (This won't work because Javascript don't allow importing of numbers)
3. Get the API data and setState to currentIcon as `currentIco: ./WeatherIcons/${current.weather[0].icon}.svg`
4. Use image source accordingly to the data. `<img src={this.state.currentIcon} />`

Thanks for looking into this question. I appreciate your help please ping me if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can't use variables that start with a number. But you can rewrite your import statement.

```
import 01d from "./WeatherIcons/10d.svg"
```

The previous code means you just import the default export. And you can name the default what you want.

Consider the following example:

```
import defaultIcon from "./WeatherIcons/10d.svg"

import {namedIcon} from './allIcons'
```

This translates into the following code (edited):

```
var importHelperVar = require("./WeatherIcons/10d.svg");

var defaultIcon = importHelperVar && importHelperVar.__esModule ? importHelperVar : { default: importHelperVar };

var allIcons = require("./allIcons");
var namedIcon = allIcons.namedIcon;
```

This means you can just rename your icon and are good to go.